# A/B, multivariant testing with spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, ab-testing

I'd like to start an A/B testing and/or multivariant testing experience in an existing e-commerce website. This website is heavily relying on vanilla Spring + Spring MVC.

Many analytics products (like Google Content Experiments) handle stats collection + variant selection; you basically have to create one URL per variant (and configure each URL in GCE).

One could use:

- [HandlerInterceptors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) to select the Handler at runtime
- [Theme resolvers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-themeresolver) to choose CSS/static resources at runtime

Do these techniques match this use case?

Do you have experience with A/B testing or multivariant testing with Spring MVC?

Or maybe you think these features should be handled by a particular JavaScript framework, like [cohorts](https://github.com/jamesyu/cohorts)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had experience dealing with multivariant and a/b testing while using [Omniture](http://www.omniture.com/en/products/online-business-optimisation).  You could almost certainly do everything that these testing suites do yourself, but you would have to build an awful lot of infrastructure to accommodate the variants **and** collate the relevant data **and** display it back in a meaningful way to those who are interested.  Given the sheer volume of options that any of these types of testing suites come with, it would probably take a great deal of time to replicate this type of function on your own.

If you have the budget, I would recommend using one of the many tools that are specialized in doing this sort of thing.  Of course, if you don't have the budget but have the time, I can see where building it yourself could be a lot of fun...

I'm not sure how much of an 'answer' this is more than just my opinion.

Comment: That's the path I've taken since I asked this question. And I've come to the same conclusions myself. So your opinion works for me!

Comment: You know, I didn't even realize how old this was.  Totally didn't mean to necro this on you.  You got me in nostalgia mode thinking about all the things I *don't* have to do anymore: eg, dealing with Omniture.